# Accessing arguments passed to as_view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to access arguments passed to `as_view` in the view class code?

```
url(r'^api/business/$',
    RandomView.as_view(key='BUSINESS'),
    name='business'),
```

In my view class, how would I access `key='BUSINESS'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you investigate what happens with the attributes passed to as_view method, you'd find this in main View class which is parent to all views :

```
 if not hasattr(cls, key):
        raise TypeError("%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
                            "only accepts arguments that are already "
                            "attributes of the class." % (cls.__name__, key))
```

So, in your `RandomView` class, add a class attribute `key`

```
class RandomView( ... ):
    key = None
```

And you can easily access the value of this attribute where you need.

Comment: More specifically, you will be able to do `self.key`.